# Creating a Vim function mapping that takes a count

Tags: key-bindings, range, count

I'm trying to create a function mapping that takes a count, in this case the number of lines to yank to the system clipboard.

```
func! Clipboard()
  echo 'Clipboard function called'
  if v:count is 0
    normal "+yy
  else
    exec 'normal ' . v:count . '"+yy'
  endif
endfunc
nmap YY :call Clipboard()<CR>
```

Problem is it's being called multiple times when a count is provided and even then the clipboard ends up with only one entry. Pretty bizarre.

e.g. with this text

```
first line
second line
third line
fourth line
fifth line
sixth line
seventh line
eighth line
```

I place the cursor at 'first line' and hit '4YY' and the clipboard ends up with these lines:

```
fourth line
fifth line
sixth line
seventh line
```

How's this happening?
The messages printed are:

```
4 lines yanked
4 lines yanked
4 lines yanked
4 lines yanked
```

If the function is really being called 4 times like the message says, why do I have only one entry in the clipboard?

Comment: `:h func-range`, or use `:<C-u>call Clipboard()<CR>` in your map.

Comment: My gvim can't find help for func-range. Works perfectly though. But how?

Comment: Using `range`, the function handles the range itself (`a:firstline`, `a:lastline`), so it's called only once. See [here](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#E124). The other approach (using `<C-u>`) works too - you clear the range prior to calling your function, so it's called only once, but you still have access to `v:count` (also `v:count1`) - so it's probably easier to use in your case.

Comment: BTW your exercise could be resumed to: `noremap YY :y<cr>`, with visual mode support.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Not going to pretend I understand all that, maybe someday. What's important is that it works for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(just to move the relevant comments in an answer)*

Use `range`, so that the function handles the range itself (`a:firstline`, `a:lastline`), so it's called only once. See [here](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#E124) (`:h func-range`).

Another approach: use `:<C-u>call Clipboard()<CR>` in your map. You clear the range prior to calling your function, so it's called only once, but you still have access to `v:count` (also `v:count1`) - so it's probably easier to use in your case.

Answer (score 4):

When using counts and calling functions a range will be inserted automatically by Vim. You can see this by doing simply doing `3:`. A common solution is to use `<c-u>` to remove the range. See `:h c_CTRL-U` for more help.

```
nmap YY :<c-u>call Clipboard()<CR>
```

However there are a bunch of issues worth going over:

- You should generally avoid recursive mappings. Use `noremap` variants. e.g. `nnoremap <key> lhs`
- General rule of thumb: unless you are mapping to a `<Plug>` mapping use `noremap`.
- `Y` is a Vim command and often remapped to `y$`. Your key choice will cause a delay if you want to use `Y`.
- Use `v:count1` instead of `v:count` to simplify your code. See `:h v:count1`.
- Use full names. e.g. `function` instead of `func`. This will help aid with readability.
- Probably don't want this function in the global scope. Use `s:` and `<SID>`. See `:h internal-variables` and `:h <SID>`
- This only method assumes that you only want to deal with yanking lines. Probably best to include a visual mode method as well.
- Should we be able to `d` to clipboard?
- Possibly check out `'clipboard'`. See `:h 'clipboard'`.
- Possibly make it easy to do `"+` instead of change a bunch of mappings. e.g. `nnoremap "" "+`

Comment: lol at that rate we'll end up with a plugin. I would love visual mode functionality, how do I modify it?

Comment: Visual mode mapping: `xnoremap <key> "+y`. You can experiment with using `"+y` and `"+Y` to meet your needs.